# Facebook sdk previous version

Tags: facebook

I want to access complete facebook friend list. Since in recent version it is removed. So Is there any place where i can get previous versions of facebook sdk for android. As facebook sdk v1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even if u find it. you wont be able to use it.

go with new one, previous is depricated

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter which Facebook SDK you are using. The change have been made on Facebooks servers. So if you created your app after 4/30/2014 there is no way to access API v1.0

Comment: But what about the apps that are working on previous api??? As birthday remainders...

Comment: If you have an app that was active before 4/30/2014 you have until 4/30/2015 to upgrade to API v2.0.